# Displaying a sequence of PIL images with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am generating PIL Image objects in a loop. I'd like to display these as they are generated with Tkinter.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to display the images each in a new window, or replace the old image with the new image? Or do you want to show them side-by-side?

Comment: Oops, should have made that clearer. Replace the old image with the new image, yes. Kind of like an animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `TkInter` window containing a `Label`, and each time you want to change the image, create a new `ImageTk.PhotoImage` from the old image and set the label's `image` property to the newly created `PhotoImage`. Example:

```
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk
root = Tkinter.Tk()
label = Tkinter.Label(root)
label.pack()
def change_image(image):
    photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image=photoimage)
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever you need to change the image, call `change_image()`.

Comment: So I tried this, but my image won't show up at all. Is there something else I have to do? I have done everything in your code, and I'm using root.after to call my main function, inside which it uses change_image to set the label image.

Comment: Here is a full recipe: [PIL and TkInter to display image](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/521918-pil-and-tkinter-to-display-images/)